# Need to concat two string value in two different table in KQL

Tags: azure, concatenation, kql

I need to concat with the command strcat 2 string value present on 2 different table.I use let to have the different table and join them with the command `| join kind=fullouter`

Like u can see in my screenshoot the column URL cant have the 2 value in my different table

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

With which command can I have both test values on the same url line ?

Thanks

I use join and let but cant have the value of the two different table in the same column

Comment: Share the required output. When values are not matching in the two tables, you cannot have two values in the same row.

Comment: So how can I have two different value in two different table and concat them in the same row ?

Comment: How do you join both tables? Can you share sample data of two tables? and share the output for that sample data

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information its my first post, I find another way to do my thing, so thanks for the help its working now :)

Comment: You can post the working solution here

Comment: Done in answer !

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a link with information that could be found in two different tables.

The first table (First let) doesn't have an identical value to share with the 2nd table (the 2nd let).
So I made it look as if the value existed in the 1st table with a strcat and did the same in the 2nd table. The two values were then identical. After my join I was able to add the information from both tables to the final strcat link.
The variable **WebsiteID** is found in the first let (a watchlist) and the 2nd variable **incidentID** is found in the 2nd let, a product table.

I didn't immediately understand that we had to use two identical values in order to be able to work on them. There's probably a simpler way, but it works.

I tried to put the important information in bold in the code section but it didn't work, so it's between **.

```
let WatchListClient =_GetWatchlist('CustomerInfo')
**| extend URL = strcat("https://website.com/detections/");**
let WithS = Custom_CL
| extend Name = tostring(split(userSam, '\\', 1)[0]),
         NTDomain = tostring(split(userSam, '\\', 0)[0])
**| extend URL = strcat("https://website.com/detections/");**
WithS
| join kind=inner WatchListClient on URL
| extend URL = strcat("https://website.com/detections",**incidentId**,"?scopeCustomerId=", **WebSiteID**)
| summarize any(*) by incidentId
```